# TouchesMoved with Button?

Tags: iphone, button, uiimageview, touchesmoved

Is it possible to use the `touchesMoved` function with buttons instead of `UIImageView`s?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In your .h file

```
IBOutlet UIButton *aButton;
```

In your .m file

```
    -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(p1.frame, location)) 
    {
        if (!p1.isHighlighted){
            [self pP01];
            [p1 setHighlighted:YES];
    }
}else {
        [p1 setHighlighted:NO];
    }
    //
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(p2.frame, location)) 
    {
        if (!p2.isHighlighted){
            [self pP02];
            [p2 setHighlighted:YES];
        }
    }else {
        [p2 setHighlighted:NO];
    }
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(p3.frame, location))
    {
        if (!p3.isHighlighted){
            [self pP03];
            [p3 setHighlighted:YES];
        }
    }else {
        [p3 setHighlighted:NO];
    }
}
```

And finally, in Interface Builder, connect your button to 'aButton' and **turn off** "User Interaction Enabled" for your button.
This is important because it allow touchesMoved to handle it.

I have adjusted the code above to check the buttons highlighted state. This is to stop it from firing the button multiple times when you drag your finger inside the area.

To get your "piano keys" to work when you tap them, use `-(void)touchesBegan`

To  set your button highlight states back to `= NO;`, use `-(void)touchesEnded`

I have had to find out the exact same thing you are after. I couldn't figure out `Touch Drag Enter`

So to avoid multiple posts on the subject, please check out my question and answers.

[question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286305/how-do-you-get-multiple-touch-buttons-to-work-with-touchesbegan-moved)

[question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234822/how-to-call-a-method-only-once-during-voidtouchesmoved)

Comment: heey.. thx for your answer but i got this warning "request for member `view`in something not a structure or union" by the line UITouch *touch = [[event....!
i changed this line in     UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject]; and it work. But.. =) if i press my button it should sound a note. But now i cant press, only slide. And if i slide in my Button the note sounds more than once.. can you help me? thank you for your answer. i saw it only now. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly find the 'view' that is currently being touch event is dragging over even if it is a button. You could also use the 'touch drag enter' connection for buttons in the Interface Builder. Look at the connections tab by pressing cmd+2 when having selected a button.