# How to call a method only once during -(void)touchesMoved?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitouch, touchesmoved

I am using `- (void) touchesMoved` to do stuff when ever I **enter** a specific frame, in this case the area of a button.

My problem is, I only want it to do stuff when I enter the frame - **not** when I am moving my finger inside the frame.

Does anyone know how I can call my methods only once while I am inside the frame, and still allow me to call it once again if I re-enter it in the same touchMove.

Thank you.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(p1.frame, location))
    {
            //I only want the below to me called 
            // once while I am inside this frame
        [self pP01];
        [p1 setHighlighted:YES];
    }else {
        [p1 setHighlighted:NO];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some attribute to check if the code was already called when you were entering specific area. It looks like highlighted state of `p1` object (not sure what it is) may be appropriate for that:

```
if(CGRectContainsPoint(p1.frame, location))
{
   if (!p1.isHighlighted){ // We entered the area but have not run highlighting code yet
        //I only want the below to me called 
        // once while I am inside this frame
      [self pP01];
      [p1 setHighlighted:YES];
   }
}else { // We left the area - so we'll call highlighting code when we enter next time
    [p1 setHighlighted:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Simply add a BOOL` that you check in touchesMoved and reset in touchesEnded

Comment: you need to reset this bool flag also when you exit the required area: see "and still allow me to call it once again if I re-enter it in the same touchMove." requirement in the question

Answer (score 1):

```
if( CGRectContainsPoint([p1 frame],[touch locationInView:self.view])) {
   NSLog (@"Touch Moved over p1");
  if (!p14.isHighlighted) {
   [self action: p1];
   p1.highlighted = YES; 
   }
  }else {
   p1.highlighted = NO;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a UIButton and use the 'touch drag enter' connection in Interface Builder.