# Finger drag on your buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Assume that a five buttons side by side, I need to know how to make them accept (called) the drag from outside to inside the border of each button.

i.e. Like the piano if you drag your finger every button called and make sound

Comment: +1 for a witty question title :)

Comment: The title is nonsensical, and the question is excessively brief, so I am voting to close.

Comment: The question author indicates below that this is a duplicate: [TouchesMoved with Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218613/touchesmoved-with-button)

Answer (score 2):

You should add a handler for the 'drag enter' event for each button - I'm not sure that you can do this in interface builder but here's how to do it in code.

Put this in your viewDidLoad method :

```
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEntered:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];
[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEntered:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];
[button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEntered:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];
[button4 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEntered:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];
[button5 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEntered:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];
```

and then

```
- (void)buttonEntered:(UIButton *)button {
    NSLog(@"Dragged into %@", button);
}
```

Have a [look at this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlEvents) for the different types of control events you can listen for.

NB This example assumes that you have got this in your .h file :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button4;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button5;
```

and connected them correctly in interface builder etc.

Comment: Hello, first thanks for the answer second I did what u had written but i got 2 warning and the Viewdidload stop maybe i forgot somthing can u help me more plz

Comment: I can only help if you tell me what the warnings were ;)

Comment: ok in the void method warning passing arrgument 1 of "NSLog" from incompatible pointer type second warning: 'AVAudioPlayer' may not respond to '-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:' i did what u told me plus in the .h file i wrote the signature of ur void method

Comment: The first warning is easy, its just a typo! I missed out a '@' - I've edited the question to fix it.

Comment: The second error is more complicated - it looks like button1 is an AVAudioPlayer, not a UIButton as your question implied. My code will only work on objects that inherit from UIControl, like UIbuttons etc. An AVAudioPlayer isn't a view so I don't see how you can be putting it onto the screen and expecting it to be touched?

Comment: Now all work properly but the simulator stop and show me a blak screen if i comment the [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEntered:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter]; the application work but why this is really wired

Comment: It's not weird at all - you're calling a method on an object that doesn't have that method so it crashes. What is button1? If you're using interface builder you should have a line like `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;` somewhere in your .h file?

Comment: ok ok thank u, your is code great i solve it, it is my problem i confused between the button name and the sound name i passed the sound name not the button it seem work but can i test it in the simulator ?

Comment: Ah, that would explain it :) It should work in the simulator or on a phone, I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't. Glad to help.

Comment: ok thank u again i will try in my phone but today i got the approve from Apple to be a developer and till now i doesn't submit my iPhone

Comment: hello again nothing done in the device still the IBAction not called